# rxJava2 how to aggregate arrays based on size

Tags: rx-java2, reactive

Imagine a `Flowable<byte[]>` that emits byte arrays of various size. I would like to transform this `Flowable` so that it emits arrays of fixed size. I scanned through all the operators but couldn't find something that matches this usecase.

I looked at `generate` but I can't see a way of hooking it up with flowing byte arrays from upstream. I guess it's not designed for this.

Comment: You need a very special operator for this, such as [partialCollect](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowabletransformerspartialcollect) but the rebatching logic on itself could be non-trivial.

Comment: How do I end up with use cases that always need special something :D. Thanks for the push in the right direction. I am reading the doc for the operator and will try to apply it here.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, which is heavily based on the example from the documentation of the `partialCollect` operator. Thanks again @akarnokd for jumping in.

```java
protected FlowableTransformer<byte[], byte[]> normalize(int size)
{
    return
        FlowableTransformers.partialCollect(
            (Consumer<PartialCollectEmitter<byte[], Integer, ByteBuffer, byte[]>>) emitter -> {
                Integer idx = emitter.getIndex();
                if (idx == null) {
                    idx = 0;
                }
                ByteBuffer bb = emitter.getAccumulator();
                if (bb == null) {
                    bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
                    emitter.setAccumulator(bb);
                }

                if (emitter.demand() != 0) {

                    boolean d = emitter.isComplete();
                    if (emitter.size() != 0) {
                        byte[] bytes = emitter.getItem(0);

                        int delta = size - bb.position();

                        if (enoughBytesToEmit(bytes, idx, delta)) {
                            bb.put(bytes, idx, delta);
                            byte[] bytesToEmit =
                                prepareBytesToEmit(bb);
                            emitter.next(bytesToEmit);

                            if (arrayHasMoreBytes(bytes, idx, delta)) {
                                idx = idx + delta;
                            } else {
                                idx = 0;
                                emitter.dropItems(1);
                            }
                        } else {
                            bb.put(bytes, idx, bytes.length - idx);
                            emitter.dropItems(1);
                            idx = 0;
                        }
                    } else if (d) {
                        if (bb.position() != 0) {
                            byte[] result = prepareBytesToEmit(bb);
                            emitter.next(result);
                        }
                        emitter.complete();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                emitter.setIndex(idx);
            }, Functions.emptyConsumer(), 128);

}

private byte[] prepareBytesToEmit(ByteBuffer bb)
{
    int size = bb.position();
    bb.flip();
    byte[] result = new byte[size];
    bb.get(result);
    bb.clear();

    return result;
}

private boolean enoughBytesToEmit(byte[] bytes, int idx, int delta)
{
    return bytes.length - idx >= delta;
}

private boolean arrayHasMoreBytes(byte[] bytes, int idx, int delta)
{
    return idx + delta < bytes.length;
}
```